# How to link G+ View profile intent in android

Tags: android, google-plus

I have integrated G+ to my app. I am trying out something similar to Google plus or playstore  G+ view profile...

If I click the view profile. Profile details in Google plus app is opened.

Does anybody know how to call this particular activity - I would like apply the URI in my App too?

The screen shot below from playstore app:

[image: From Playstore App]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out a way to do it:

```
 startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://plus.google.com/"+userID+"/posts")));
```

This will prompt user to open through browser or APP and then it will show the profile details accordingly!

Hope this will be useful for others!

Thanks!